# Blank data being displayed in Report preview for few rows which has length greater than 38 (The data type is Varchar(60))

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssms

I'm having an issue with report preview in Reporting services.
Blank data being displayed in Report preview only for few rows which have a length greater than 38( the data type for the field is Varchar(60)).) But in SQL Server able to see the data. Even the Query designer in the data set also displays the expected data. When  I preview the report, then, for few rows it is displaying the blank value. I tried refreshing the data set/ adding a new field (given a new name) and used the source field for this new field/Changed font size /added new tablix and tried out/added new data set and tried out. But nothing worked out. Still, it is displaying blank data for a few rows. Can anyone pls. help with getting out of this issue?

Comment: First thing I think of is - is there whitespace in the stored values? Try using `LTRIM(RTRIM())` in your query. You can also try exporting to Excel and checking to see if it exports the values.

Comment: No Bjones, Adding LTRIM RTRIM not working out. It still displays the same data.

Comment: Did you export to Excel and check the data within Excel?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's coming blank only. Even the value doesn't have spaces in l and rtims.

Comment: If you create a new report, copy the dataset and add a simple table/matrix can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Alan Schofied I've not tried that. But I hardcoded the same value and tried out. Able to view the data without blank. I tried in separate environment.

Comment: I would check for things like carriage returns in the string then. You might have one or more that forces the text into a new line outside the boundary of the text bix

Comment: Thanks @BJones & Alan Schofield for trying it out. I found the solution for this. Actually in server1 the value is blank and in the server2 the values are set up. The report runs based on the server1. So, only it was displaying the blank data. Actually there are no issues with the report design or logic. It is fully depend on the environment it runs on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fact that you're using two different servers would be a good detail to add to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @BJones & @Alan Schofield for trying it out. I found the solution for this. Actually, in server1 the value is blank and in the server2 the values are set up. The report runs based on the server1. So, only it was displaying the blank data. Actually, there are no issues with the report design or logic. It fully depends on the environment it runs on. Anyhow the issues solved now. I'm happy for that.